# Stuck on GraphQl query in Gatsby using imageSharp

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to get the following background prop set to a image in my src/images/bird.jpg directory. Here is my code, but I get a `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` from my graphQl query in the console and the background prop returns null in React Inspector, What am I doing wrong?

`/src/pages/index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'

import Layout from '../components/layout'

const IndexPage = ({ data }) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <p>{data.site.siteMetadata.title}</p>
    <p>{data.site.siteMetadata.desc}</p>
    <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
    <p>Now go build something great.</p>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage

export const query = graphql`
  query SiteMeta {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        desc
      }
    }
    background: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/bird.jpg/" }) {
      sizes(maxWidth: 1240) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: should it not be `relativePath: { regex: "/bird.jpg/" }` ? I had a look in their codebase and it appears that you're overriding the id, so your background gets undefined and id of the background throws the error.

Comment: Doing that gives me the following error. `error    Syntax Error: Expected Name, found {  graphql/template-strings`

Comment: Found the answer in another post, here you go https://stackoverflow.com/a/52040056/9487420